# Access bash variables in Pentaho Kettle

Tags: bash, pentaho, kettle

In my transformation,I want to have a dynamic database connection properties like host name / port /username and password, And my bash profile already contain those information. How can i access those bash profile variables through my transformation ?

Thank you,

Thusira.

Comment: Show us your `.bash_profile` and how exactly do you want to retrieve information with a minimal input example and output needed?

Comment: @Inian , my bash_profile contain following entries,


DB_PORT=27017
DB_HOST=localhost
DB_NAME=test
DB_PASSWORD=welcome1!
DB_USERNAME=testUser

Comment: The above comment is unnecessary and disrespectful. Your question had no efforts of proper research and just asking for plain _code_, and moreover its just _NOT_ complying with the [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and does  not have a verifiable input, i.e. assuming we have a solution for you, how to we test it? Read through [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), before asking questions. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

The best way to declare pentaho variables is to add them in the file `$HOME/.kettle/kettle.properties`.

These variables can be accessed in your jobs/transformations with `${..}` just like bash variables.

Example,

In `kettle.properties`,

```
DB_HOST=xx.xx.xx.xx
```

In Transformation,

```
${DB_HOST}
```

Comment: Thanks, I have tried. But if i use this method, i might have to use distinct property file for each environments. Because i have an application running on these bash variables. I am thinking of re using the same for transformation. so i don't have to change 2 places when there is a change in variables values. Do you have any idea on that.?

Comment: If updating variables  2 files is your problem, you can very well make the `kettle.properties` to read for variables from the environment.

Comment: Yes absolutely. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

A User-Defined-Java-Expression step can retrieve all environment variables:

String values = `java.lang.String.join("|", System.getenv().values())`

String names = `java.lang.String.join("|", System.getenv().keySet())`

Now Split-Field-To-Rows with numbering enabled will prepare a Merge-Join on the rownumber eventually yielding a stream with fields (name, value).

Don't be shy.